# Why is my div overlapping other divs below?

Tags: html, css

I have having an issue with my slideshow overlapping my 'learn more' message section as well as my `grid` container, but not the pink banner overlapping the message banner. I am trying to see where I am going wrong. I already made changes to make them in individual containers.

Also why is my `footer` at the top with my `nav` bar, I have attempted to change the `height` property.

```css
body {
  /* font: 15px/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; */
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #D3D3D3 0%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 10%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 90%, #D3D3D3 100%);
}

.CLASSNAME {
  position: relative
}

* {}


/*Global*/

.container {
  width: 1400px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Font*/

@font-face {
  font-family: theboldfont;
  src: url(font/theboldfont.ttf)
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 16px;
}


/*Header*/

header {
  background: #19252A;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 5px;
  min-height: 70px;
}

header a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px;
}

header li {
  /*float:left;*/
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

.logo {
  padding-left: 75px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

header .highlight,
header .current a {
  color: #e8491d;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/*Slideshow*/

.slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  height: 350px;
  width: 1400px;
}

.slide_img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}

.slide_img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#i1,
#i2,
#i3,
#i4 {
  display: none;
}

.pre,
.nxt {
  width: 12%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(88, 88, 88, -4);
  z-index: 99;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pre {
  left: 0;
}

.nxt {
  right: 0;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  bottom: 12%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
}

.dots {
  top: -55px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

.slide_img {
  z-index: -1;
}

#i1:checked~#one,
#i2:checked~#two,
#i3:checked~#three,
#i4:checked~#four {
  z-index: 9;
}

#i1:checked~.nav #dot1,
#i2:checked~.nav #dot2,
#i3:checked~.nav #dot3,
#i4:checked~.nav #dot4 {
  background: #fff;
}


/*Learn more section*/

.learn-more {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 20px;
}

.learn-more-message {
  border-bottom: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.learn-more-message p {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 30px 125px 20px 125px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.learn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 175px;
  margin: 5px;
  /* space between buttons */
  background: deeppink;
  /* background color */
  color: white;
  /* text color */
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  /* rounded corners */
  padding: 0px;
  /* space around text */
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  font-family: theboldfont;
}

.join {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 175px;
  margin: 5px;
  /* space between buttons */
  background: deeppink;
  /* background color */
  color: white;
  /* text color */
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  /* rounded corners */
  padding: 0px;
  /* space around text */
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  font-family: theboldfont;
}

div .grid-item1 {
  width: 150px;
}

div .grid-container1 {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}


/*Grid Buttons*/

.grid-container {
  width: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  font-family: theboldfont;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-image-width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: theboldfont;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
  background: #1D2428;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.box {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: deeppink;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: ;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
  border-top: 15px solid #fff;
}

.box h1 {
  font-family: theboldfont;
}

.box1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #19252A;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
  border-top: 0px solid #fff;
  font: 5px;
}

.box1 p {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 8.5px;
}


/*Find Us Map*/

.find-us-map {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.find-us,
.map,
.artcle {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .find-us {
    flex: 3;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .img {
    height: 250px;
  }
  .map {
    flex: 5;
  }
  .article {
    flex: 6;
  }
  .article img {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
  }
  .map img {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
  }
  /*Picture/Message Box*/
  .pm-box {
    display: flex;
    height: 150px;
    border-bottom: 15px solid #fff;
  }
  .picture {
    flex: 2;
    background: #19252A;
  }
  .message {
    flex: 8;
    background: #19252A;
    padding-right: 70px;
    margin: none;
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
  .message p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
  .circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 80px;
    background: white;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 5px solid black;
  }
  /*Footer*/
  * {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  }
  i {
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  i.fa.fa-facebook {
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  footer {
    background: #19252A;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .footer-container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .footer-container p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .footer-container {
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .footer-container ul {
    display: flex;
    float: right;
  }
  .footer-container ul li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .footer-container ul li a {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: centre;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 35px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .footer-container ul li a .fa {
    position: relative;
    color: #262626;
    transition: .5s;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  .footer-container ul li a:hover .fa {
    color: #fff;
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
  .footer-container ul li a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #f00;
    transition: .5s;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .footer-container ul li a:hover:before {
    top: 0;
  }
  .footer-container ul li:nth-child(1) a:before {
    background: #3b5999;
  }
  .footer-container ul li:nth-child(2) a:before {
    background: #55acee;
  }
  .footer-container ul li:nth-child(3) a:before {
    background: #cd201f;
  }
  .footer-container ul li:nth-child(4) a:before {
    background: #e4405f;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" conftent="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Nature Tours | Home</title>
  <!--Ion Icons-->
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Google Fonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aldrich&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!--Our own stylesheet-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="CLASSNAME">
        <div>
          <a href="index.html">
            <img class="logo" src="img/stars-logo.png" alt="" />
          </a>


          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="workshops.html">Workshops</a></li>

            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <input type="radio" name="images" id="i1" checked>
      <input type="radio" name="images" id="i2">
      <input type="radio" name="images" id="i3">
      <input type="radio" name="images" id="i4">

      <div class="slide_img" id="one">
        <img src="img/STARS%2027.jpg">
        <label for="i4" class="pre"></label>
        <label for="i2" class="nxt"></label>

      </div>

      <div class="slide_img" id="two">
        <img src="img/STARS%2027.jpg">
        <label for="i1" class="pre"></label>
        <label for="i3" class="nxt"></label>
      </div>

      <div class="slide_img" id="three">
        <img src="img/STARS%2027.jpg">
        <label for="i2" class="pre"></label>
        <label for="i4" class="nxt"></label>
      </div>

      <div class="slide_img" id="four">
        <img src="img/STARS%2027.jpg">
        <label for="i3" class="pre"></label>
        <label for="i1" class="nxt"></label>
      </div>

      <div class="nav">
        <label class="dots" id="dot1" for="i1"></label>
        <label class="dots" id="dot2" for="i2"></label>
        <label class="dots" id="dot3" for="i3"></label>
        <label class="dots" id="dot4" for="i4"></label>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>



  <div class="container">
    <div class="learn-more-message">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore.
      </p>

      <div class="grid-container1">

        <a class="learn" title="Relevant Title" href="#">Learn More</a>

        <a class="join" title="Relevant Title" href="join-our-school.html">Join Our School</a>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--   <section class="Learn-more-buttons">
        </section> -->

  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid-container">
      <a href="workshops.html">
        <div class="grid-item" style="background-image: url(img/STARS%2024.jpg)">Lorem</div>
      </a>
      <a href="our-classes.html">
        <div class="grid-item" style="background-image: url(img/STARS%2023.jpg)">Lorem</div>
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <div class="grid-item" style="background-image: url(img/STARS%2028.jpg)">Lorem</div>
      </a>
      <a href="our-teachers.html">
        <div class="grid-item" style="background-image: url(img/STARS%2016.jpg)">Lorem</div>
      </a>
      <a href="our-kids.html">
        <div class="grid-item" style="background-image: url(img/STARS%2026.jpg)">Lorem</div>
      </a>
      <a href="workshops.html">
        <div class="grid-item" style="background-image: url(img/STARS%2013.jpg)">Lorem</div>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="container">
    <section class="join-our-school">
      <a href="join-our-school.html">
        <div class="box">
          <h1>Lorem</h1>

        </div>
      </a>
    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="pm-box">
      <div class="picture">
        <div class="circle">
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="message">
        <p style="color: #ffffff">

          "Sed tristique augue tellus. Vestibulum sagittis vestibulum nibh, at rutrum nisi faucibus eu. Mauris eget nisl eleifend, dignissim ante vel, convallis eros. Phasellus urna eros, facilisis et faucibus sit amet, bibendum quis diam. Curabitur ornare ultricies
          pulvinar."
          <br />
          <br /> -Napet, COMOGET Seque.

        </p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>




  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer-container">


      <p>
        STARS Performing Arts School, Create Studios, 120A Hartopp Road, Clarendon Park, Leicester, LE2 1WF<br/>Copyright &copy; 2009-2017 STARS - Su Tucker Academy Reaching Stars
      </p>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      </ul>






    </div>
  </div>




  <script>
    type = "text/javascript"
    src = "scripts.js
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The slideshow itself and the elements in you footer are `position: abolsute`.
Remove this on the `.slideshow` , `.footer-container p` and `.footer-container ul`.